# In spring batch remote partitioning can we have the master and slave configuration as a single configuration and run it as a single program

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm using remote partitioning for my project and I have 2 projects in eclipse, i.e one is the master program and a separate one for the Slave. Instead of having 2 projects separately , Can I combine the slave and master to a single context and run, master and slave as a single Java process in my JVM?

Comment: If your end result from a deployment perspective is to run all within a single JVM, you may also want to take a look at the `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler`.  It uses threads in process to process the partitions (no need for the messaging/spring integration): http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.html

Comment: @MichaelMinella: Thank you, I have implemented Remote partitioning using activeMQ and my requirement is to run slaves in 4 nodes. For load balancing we are planning to deploy the master jobs also in the 4 nodes. (Same Master with partitioner and partition handler and same set of slaves with exact remote step configuration with reader , writer and processor are to be deployed in the 4 nodes.). In this case I'm planing to deploy a single application in all the 4 nodes which will have a master config and slave config. They can act as a Master and a slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the common pattern - with the master participating as one of the "slaves". If you don't need to distribute the work across multiple JVMs, the partitioning doesn't need to use an external broker; see the [batch integration test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition) and in particular the [vanilla one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/VanillaIntegrationTests-context.xml).

Comment: Thank you gary,
I started with a Simple Batch Job for which there is a Master configuration (Separate project in eclipse with its own config) and separate project with config for a slave. I need to know whether instead of master and a slave can I have a single project that can be deployed in all the 4 nodes , which can be a master do the partitions and slave will listen to the JMS queue and execute the step configured in the PartitonHandler.

Comment: Those examples do just that - any one of the instances can perform the role of master and the other instances (including the master) will process partitions.